# Bootstrap Carousel cards to be positioned from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm using Bootstrap Cards in a horizontal carousel, each has a dynamic height based on the copy length but currently they appear positioned to the bottom of the carousel, rather than the desired effect of to the top.

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/cleaton/pen/NWRNOQX)

```
  <div class="scrollmenu">

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this answer will help you  :)

```
.scrollmenu{
    display: inline-flex;
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! Out of interest, is there a way to do it without stretching the card background?